# Micronaut multipart upload - error: "Required argument [CompletedFileUpload] not specified"

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-rest

I'm trying to upload a multipart file using Micronaut without success.

I'm receiving 400 status code with message: "Required argument [CompletedFileUpload file] not specified".

```
curl -v  -F "file=@image.jpg" localhost:8080/test/param1/param2
```

How can I make it work with CompletedFileUpload?

kotlin:

```
@Controller("/test")
class DemoController(private val fileService: FileService) {

    @Post(
        "/{param1}/{param2}",
        consumes = [MULTIPART_FORM_DATA],
        produces = [TEXT_PLAIN]
    )
    @ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)
    fun post(
        file: CompletedFileUpload,
        param1: String,
        param2: String
    ) : HttpResponse<String>{

        println(file.contentType)

        fileService.uploadFile("fileName", file.inputStream)
        return HttpResponse.ok("Uploaded")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Micronaut 4.2.1), the problem was caused by using Tomcat instead of Netty. The only implementation of CompletedFileUpload is NettyCompletedFileUpload, so it probably doesn't work with a runtime other than Netty. Additionally, the key in the form must match the argument name ('file').

Answer (score 0):

The following Java code works for me (Windows cURL + Micronaut 2.5.4):

```java
package com.example;

import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
import io.micronaut.http.multipart.CompletedFileUpload;
import io.micronaut.scheduling.TaskExecutors;
import io.micronaut.scheduling.annotation.ExecuteOn;

@Controller("/test")
public class DemoController {

    @ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)
    @Post(value = "/{param1}/{param2}", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public HttpResponse<String> post(CompletedFileUpload file, String param1, String param2) {
        System.out.println("Param1: " + param1 + " Param2: " + param2 + " File name: " + file.getFilename() + " Size: " + file.getSize() + " Type: " + file.getContentType().get());
        return HttpResponse.ok("Uploaded!");
    }
}
```

cURL command:

```
.\curl.exe -v  -F "file=@dummy.pdf" localhost:8080/test/param1/param2
*   Trying ::1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /test/param1/param2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 13456
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------2252ddfaf1589615
>
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 31 May 2021 17:52:23 GMT
< content-type: text/plain
< content-length: 9
< connection: keep-alive
<
Uploaded!* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Output:

```
Param1: param1 Param2: param2 File name: file Size: 13264 Type: application/pdf
```

Does the Java code work for you? Maybe this is some Kotlin/Groovy (?) related problems [with static imports/short form?]

Comment: I think @swaechter it's because I created intentionally the project as "Function Application for Serverless" with Micronaut Launch. Does it works for you with that setup?.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the name that is used for the uploaded file must match the name of the parameter, otherwise I get a 400.